# How to subscribe to Observable of Component injected via @angular/cdk/portal?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cdk

I'm trying to implement a basic (very basic) modal implementation.  I've got a `ModalService` and a `ModalComponent`.

The `ModalService` creates an instance of the `ModalComponent` and injects it into the page using the @angular/cdk/portal.

I can get the modal to display just fine :-)

The `ModalComponent` has an Observable property that I want the `ModalService` to subscribe to so that when the 'close' button is clicked within the modal, a value can be emitted and the `ModalService` can close the modal.

However, when the component emits the value, the Service is not acting on it.  From the Service side, it looks like I'm subscribed, but from the Component side, it shows 0 observers.

I thought maybe I could use a typical `@Output()` EventEmitter, but I'm not sure to hook that up since the in the modal class, since the child element doesn't exist initially.

I'm thinking maybe my component reference is not quite right (maybe I have 2 different ones?).  I'm trying suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526809/1858357)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Service**

```
export class ModalService {

    private modalPortal: ComponentPortal<any>;
    private bodyPortalHost: DomPortalHost;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                private appRef: ApplicationRef,
                private injector: Injector) {
    }

    showModal(modalName: string) {

        // set up the portal and portal host
        this.modalPortal = new ComponentPortal(ModalComponent);
        this.bodyPortalHost = new DomPortalHost(
            document.body,
            this.componentFactoryResolver,
            this.appRef,
            this.injector);

        // display the component in the page
        let componentRef = this.bodyPortalHost.attach(this.modalPortal);


        // listen for modal's close event
        componentRef.instance.onModalClose().subscribe(() => {
            console.log('I will be very happy if this this gets called, but it never ever does');
            this.closeModal();
        });

        // console.log(componentRef.instance.onModalClose()) shows 1 subscriber.
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.bodyPortalHost.detach();
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class ModalComponent {

    private modalClose: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    onModalClose(): Observable<any> {
        return this.modalClose.asObservable();
    }

    closeModal() {
        // console.log(this.onModalClose()) **shows zero observers**   :-(
        this.modalClose.next();
        this.modalClose.complete();
    }
}
```

Also, if I happen to be asking the wrong question, meaning there's a better overall approach, I'm open to suggestions. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: You're supposed to append `this` to indicate that the property is part of the class. (a.k.a. `console.log(onModalClose())` should be `console.log(this.onModalClose())`

Comment: thanks for the comment @Edric, but I was actually using `this`, I just omitted it from my question by mistake.  I updated the code above.

Comment: Please check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwrgpo?file=app/modal.service.ts looks like it works properly

Comment: Oh, wow! I appears to be working there.

Comment: same exact code eh?  Now I have to figure out why this isn't working locally..!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say THANK YOU! :-) @yurzui

Comment: When I posted this question, i included simplified code.  As @yurzui pointed out, the simplified code actually works!  I figured out what my problem was.  The component that I was injecting was actually a specialized modal (CustomModal) that included the Modal directive inside.  So, the elementRef I was getting from the ModalService was to the outer CustomModal and not the Modal itself.  I corrected this by simply subscribing the CustomModal to the Modal events and re-emitting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me with very few changes, so I'm confused as to what your problem is.  First I created a project with the Angular CLI using `ng new`.  Then I installed ng material using the [instructions on their site](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

I created a modal service which is identical to yours:

```
    import {ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {DomPortalHost, ComponentPortal} from "@angular/cdk/portal";
import {ModalComponent} from "./modal/modal.component";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  private modalPortal: ComponentPortal<any>;
  private bodyPortalHost: DomPortalHost;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private appRef: ApplicationRef,
              private injector: Injector) {
  }

  showModal(modalName: string) {

    // set up the portal and portal host
    this.modalPortal = new ComponentPortal(ModalComponent);
    this.bodyPortalHost = new DomPortalHost(
      document.body,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.appRef,
      this.injector);

    // display the component in the page
    let componentRef = this.bodyPortalHost.attach(this.modalPortal);


    // listen for modal's close event
    componentRef.instance.onModalClose().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('I will be very happy if this this gets called, but it never ever does');
      this.closeModal();
    });

    // console.log(componentRef.instance.onModalClose()) shows 1 subscriber.
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.bodyPortalHost.detach();
  }
}
```

I created a modal component.  The TypeScript is the same as yours:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/index";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private modalClose: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  onModalClose(): Observable<any> {
    return this.modalClose.asObservable();
  }

  closeModal() {
    // console.log(this.onModalClose()) **shows zero observers**   :-(
    this.modalClose.next();
    this.modalClose.complete();
  }

}
```

You didn't give us a model for the HTML, but this is what I used:

```
<p>
  modal works!
</p>
<button (click)="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ModalService} from "src/app/modal.service";
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [ModalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note I Defined the ModalComponent in the entryComponents and the ModalService as a provider.

The app.component HTML:

```
<button (click)="showModal()">Show Modal</button>
```

And the app.component typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalService} from "./modal.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(public modalService: ModalService){}

  showModal(){
       this.modalService.showModal("This is the modal name");
  }

}
```

I injected the ModalService into the constructor and called your showModal method in response to the button click in the main app.

Load the app:
[image: Initial App Load]

Click the button and the modal shows up.  It doesn't look like a modal, but that could be because of missing styling :

[image: App with Modal Shown]

Now click the close button inside the modal:

[image: Modal Closed]

You see the modal is gone and the console output displays your message.

Does this post help you find the tidbit you missed?

---

One thing to add.  If you want to send data out of your modal to the component that called it, ust change your modalComponent's closeModal method:

```
  closeModal() {
    // console.log(this.onModalClose()) **shows zero observers**   :-(
    this.modalClose.next('Your Data Here, it can be an object if need be');
    this.modalClose.complete();
  }
```

And your modal service can access the data in the `onModalClose().subscribe()` method:

```
componentRef.instance.onModalClose().subscribe((results) => {
  console.log(results);
  console.log('I will be very happy if this this gets called, but it never ever does');
  this.closeModal();
});
```

Comment: Hey @JeffryHouser, thanks for the write up.  I'm assuming you didn't notice in the comments on the question, @yurzui pointed out that my code was already working and I commented on the fix.  This happened because my 'minimal example` for this post was simpler from my original code, in a way that actually made it work.  Anyway, thanks for the work putting together the code and screenshots for future visitors who find this question! Bounty awarded :-)

Comment: Also, it's nice you pointed out about the **`entryComponents`**, as it is required  I will mention that I learned about it in my original attempts, because I didn't have it configured initially, but Angular has awesome console logging that specifically mentioned to add it, go Angular Team!

Comment: @BizzyBob I didn't notice that in the comments until after I wrote this up.  I wish I read them first; as it would have saved me some time.  Thanks for the bounty.  I'm glad you're all set; hopefully this write-up will help someone else in the future.